# How does auto-fill based on three values work?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How does auto-fill based exactly on three values work? What is the algorithm?

I mean, imagine you have three values in three consecutive cells in a row (1;2;4 e.g). You select them, then you drag the bottom right corner of the third cell. You let auto-fill four other cells. The result looks similar to this:

```
1;  2;  4;  5,333333333;    6,833333333;    8,333333333;    9,833333333
```

How did Excel come up with those last four values? What's the algorithm?

No need to be too formal in your answer. I bet it's something trivial. However I wasn't able to find the answer so far.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Did it actually skip 7? What version of Excel are you using? Were these cells part of an existing sheet? Or is this a fresh/new sheet with no formatting?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it did skip 7. I copied those values straight from Excel to PSPad and then to this website. I added only the semicolons. I am using Excel 2010 and I used a new sheet with no formating for this example. All the other cells are blank/empty/unedited.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Disregard my question about the number 7. I didn't see the pattern you had in the initial numbers (1, 2, 4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel is using **linear regression** to guess the subsequent values.

If you plot the values as a graph, its approximating a straight line though the X,Y co-ordinates of the given values. Based on this it calculates a slope and Y-axis intercept, which is then used to calculate the subsequent values :

[image]

You can read more here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression